# Alternative representation for DICOM UID in C

Tags: c, dicom

The DICOM standard defines an UID with the following rules (see [9.1 UID Encoding Rules](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/chapter_9.html#sect_9.1)). Basically all UIDs match the following regex: `[0-9.]{64}`.
So the naive representation would be something like this in C:

Using a typedef:

```
typedef char (uid_t)[64];
```

Using a struct:

```
typedef struct { char repr[64]; } UID
```

This requires 64 bytes of storage, and requires calling something like `memcmp` or `strcmp` for comparison of two instances.

The above representation allow representing up to `(2^8)^64 ~ 1.3407807929942597e+154` different UIDs.

However if one looks carefully at the representation (if we omit the rule where first digit of component shall not be zero). We see that there are only `(10 + 1)^64 ~ 4.4579156845259026e+66` possible UIDs (and we have plenty of room).

Since `(2^8)^32 ~ 1.157920892373162e+77` I can now replace my initial naive representation with:

Using a typedef:

```
typedef char (uid_t)[32];
```

Using a struct:

```
typedef struct { char repr[32]; } UID
```

So my question is:

- Which transformation will be able to convert my initial input of 64 bytes UID: `[0-9.]{64}` into this 32 bytes representation ?
- Bonus point if this is fast !

Comment: This is not a computer science question. Migrating to [SO].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking that I could do simply a [packed BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) representation:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t v01 : 4; // [0-9] -> [0b - 0b1001] and '.' (0b1010)
  uint8_t v02 : 4; // 
} dummy;

typedef struct
{
  dummy array[32];
} UID;
```

This should be faster than a simple base conversion algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description of UIDs, they are simply encoded in base 11. Your suggested representation is base 256. All you have to do is use a base conversion algorithm.